# Adding to Available Site Templates in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can anyone advise me if it's possible to add a site template to the available Site Templates on SharePoint Online?  I've run the Get-SPOWebTemplate and returned the following set.

[image: SPO Tenancy Templates]

I've created a site based on one of these and customised it to the point that I'd like to use it as the root site for future site collections, so I've taken a template/WSP of it.  Thus, my question is either: -

- How can I add my Site Template to those available to the Tenant?  OR
- What other ways can I consider to successfully use my Site Template as the root site for a new site collection?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You won't be able to, templates to provision collections would be at the farm level and we don't have access to that. There are a lot of provisioning examples on the PnP Github repo, https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples

Comment: This is what I was suspecting but wanted to confirm.  I suppose it's not possible to point the New-SPOSite cmdlet to a URL of a sub-site and have it replicate that?  And thanks for the link, I'll get a look.

Comment: No, you have to use CSOM for that, they do have a way for you to templatize a site and use their provisioning engine to create instances off that, I thought it was for webs only though and not sites (I haven't tried it). We are templatizing the provisioning aspect by having business rules wrapping new-sposite but not doing any customization or branding in SPO.

Comment: Right, it's the CSOM / Powershell trick you mention that I'm looking for.  Any links that you can refer me too?

Comment: From the github repo, this is probably the closest https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Provisioning.SiteCollectionCreation. Vesa has a great overview but it is a little dated, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2013/08/23/site-provisioning-techniques-and-remote-provisioning-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: Excellent.  Many thanks.  Let me try this and will mark up accordingly